# Open two links with separate tab only on first click to Webpage anywhere

Tags: php, jquery, html, tabs

I want to Open 2 New Tabs with 2 other Links when ever user first click anywhere on the webpage!

This action should be perform only first click not more. If anyone know then suggest me.

I had set up a popup box with a img I have these 2 tabs open script for image who ever clicks on the image 2 new tabs with new website links opens check if you can modify it

```
<a href="LINK 1" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('LINK 2'); return true;"><IMG src="IMAGE LINK HERE" ALT="Home" overflow:hidden; width:744px; height:339px;"></a>
```

Comment: Okay, and what have you done so far to accomplish this? Sounds more like an HTML/JS question than PHP..

Comment: I had set up a popup box with a img
i have this 2 tabs open script for image

who ever clicks on the image 2 new tabs with new website links opens 
check if you can modify it 

<a href="LINK 1"  target="_blank" onclick="window.open('LINK 2'); return true;"><IMG  src="IMAGE LINK HERE" ALT="Home" overflow:hidden; width:744px; height:339px;"></a>

Comment: Add code to your question.

Comment: *"Open 2 New Tabs with 2 other Links when ever user **first click anywhere on the screen***" so in other words just like how alot of sites do their pop-ups, but you want to annoy the users even more by adding even MORE tabs.

Comment: not annoy users can use those 2 websites also for their use only!

Comment: Yeah, this would be pretty annoying as a user...

Answer (score 1):

it can be done in javascript.

in order to open tabs on click you can use the following code:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',onClick,true);   // Attach click event to the document body
function onClick() {
    // open 2 tabs 
    window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');
    window.open("http://www.cnn.com", '_blank');        
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', onClick, true); // Remove attached clicked event
}
```

Inside the onClick you remove the click event ...
Work on all browsers > IE8

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not appear to work http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/unzjakt0/4/

Comment: that's because you html is empty :) 
Please try this one:  http://jsfiddle.net/7pvu4ek8/

Comment: Im not sure how that would matter, but it still doesnt work in the new fiddle

Comment: it is because the event is attached to the document body and in your jsFiddle the html was empty so the body tag was not there anyway what you did on order to test this script? because for me it works.. In order to test it you need to click on the content (on the bottom right side in jsFiddle) just click anywhere there and you will see that 2 tabs will be opened

Comment: Opened the link and clicked on "test2" which should be in the body, Maybe because Im using a Mac? Doesnt do anything for me

Comment: i am also a mac user ... maybe you have a popup blocker or something? I tested it on both chrome and Safari and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96626/discussion-between-ran-hassid-and-delightedd0d).

Comment: It appears that this does work in most browsers, just doesnt work in Chrome Canary on Mac for some reason

Comment: Hello! thanks for the Answer! 
can you please guide me to put this on my website :/
i am a newbie and i dont know how to use this! 

i had pasted it in HTML but doesnt work, i had created a .js file and then included in HTML but seems doesnt work!

I guess i am not able to put it in a perfect way please guide me!

my website : www.likelo.in

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your website ?

Comment: Nope not using jQuery!

Comment: please post  a new question so i will be able to post you an answer with code on how it can be done...